# Using TCPDF to Convert specific div to PDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have a web application written in javascript. At the end of the application, the user is presented with a receipt that shows all their actions during the course of their operating the application. I want convert this receipt into a PDF file so that it can be accessed more easily (e.g., download, print, etc.) I am having trouble targeting the specific div that I wish to use as the receipt.

```
<div id="receipt"> --- Some Content --- </div>
```

I want to target the specific div 'receipt' but only at the end of the application (I am modifying the DOM a lot, and thus the receipt div contains new content each time, and is only relevant at the end). What I am wondering is whether there is some PHP command to get the HTML text from a webpage so that I can input the variable into the TCPDF PHP call:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Where the first variable is some html text.

How can I declare a variable, $html, that contains a specific div from the .html page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHP: DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to search through the HTML file and find the contents of the DIV, and then convert what it finds into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a 'print' button at the bottom of the receipt.
2. Add a javascript function at the 'onclick' event of the print button. Get the content of the receipt div ( using jquery: $('#receipt').html()  or javascript 'document.getEmementById('receipt').innerHTML'). Add this content to a hidden variable in a form. Submit the form to a dedicated php file. (<form target='_blank')
3. You got the the post data in the  dedicated php file.

   $html = $_POST['hiddenHtml'];
4. $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

Comment: Excellent. The html isn't showing up in the PDF file though. I've run a js function onclick that gets the HTML from the receipt as follows:
`function print() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("receipt").innerHTML;
    $("#hiddenhtml").value = elem;
}`
where the hiddenhtml field is an input:
`<input id="hiddenhtml" type="hidden" value=""/>`