# How to convert Specific Div element into Image & PDF with containing it's own css in Php?

Tags: php, image-processing, pdf-generation

I want to make an image and PDF of specific div area of html in php code.

What is the best way to do this.

I have searched too much but found only Online convector.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

You can see the documentation here: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

EDIT: Here's another related post for converting a specific div.
[Using TCPDF to Convert specific div to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149153/using-tcpdf-to-convert-specific-div-to-pdf)